# php form action php self

Tags: php, forms, action

I have a php form like this.

```
<form name="form1" id="mainForm" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">

</form
```

In form action I want to use page name with parameters. like `house.php?p_id=10111` . But $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] gives only the `house.php` (My page full url is `house.php?p_id=10111` like this) Please help me to solve this problem. thanks.

Comment: This is not full url. It's url + GET parameters.

Comment: @Alex Ackerman: It’s rather [path](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.3) plus [query](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.4).

Comment: yes. Alex is correct. I'm now using `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?P_id=".$id`

Comment: mixing post and get parameters is poor practice. if you're posting, then use hidden form fields to pass through any 'get'-type values.

Comment: I disagree with @MarcB that putting query string parameters in an action is bad practice. There are many sites that use query strings to determine what content (page or state) to load and use the contents of POST to carry data.

Comment: @TecBrat, Just because many sites do that doesn't mean it isn't bad practice. Say a server only passes the get or post params depending on the type of request. Then someone's left scratching their head at why their script is broken.

Comment: https://www.powderkegwebdesign.com/carry-url-variables-submitting-form-php/ was helpful for me.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

How about leaving it empty, what is wrong with that?

```
<form name="form1" id="mainForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">

</form>
```

Also, you can omit the action attribute and it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think this is the easiest and best way to do this.

Comment: By leaving it empty, breaks w3c validation (in case you care)

Comment: @jBaron Yes, that's the case in HTML5, but you can omit the empty `action=""` attribute altogether. It will validate and work as expected.

Comment: @Shef It is bad practice to use post method for same page. Browser will always alert when one refresh the page.

Comment: @Avnishalok The browser will always alert whenever someone refreshes the page after a submit. It doesn't matter if the submission is on a different page or the same page.

Comment: @Avnishalok this is what [PRG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) is for

Answer (score 15):

You can leave action blank or use this code:

```
<form name="form1" id="mainForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>">
</form>
```

Answer (score 9):

Leaving the action value blank will cause the form to post back to itself.

Answer (score 6):

You can use an echo shortcut also instead of typing  out "echo blah;" as shown below:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?=($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>">
```

Comment: This allows for XSS attacks, you need to filter/sanatize PHP_SELF

Answer (score 4):

This is Perfect. try this one :)

```
<form name="test" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
/* Html Input Fields */
</form>
```

Comment: This allows for XSS attacks, you need to filter/sanatize PHP_SELF

Answer (score 2):

Another (and in my opinion proper) method is use the `__FILE__` constant if you don't like to rely on `$_SERVER` variables.

```
$parts = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, __FILE__);
$fileName = end($parts);
echo $fileName;
```

About magic and predefined constants: [1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php), [2](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is leaving action blank `action=""` or omitting it completely from the form tag, however it is bad practice (if at all you care about it).

Incase you do care about it, the best you can do is:

```html
<form name="form1" id="mainForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . http_build_query($_GET));?>">
```

The best thing about using this is that even arrays are converted so no need to do anything else for any kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be secure use this:`<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">`