# PHP_SELF and GET parameters

Tags: php, html

When I am using $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in a form to redirect the page to itself, such as this:

```
<form method = "get" action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    ...some html
</form>
```

When the user submits the form the URI doesn't show parameters:

```
http://example.com/page.php
```

instead of this (the one I'm trying to do)

```
http://example.com.page.php?parameter=value
```

resulting in, when the user refreshes the page, it does not process the GET parameters because it is not there. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try to leave action value empty.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862735/php-form-action-php-self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put an empty form action like in the following example:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
```

All GET parameters will be preserved

Comment: Here quote not opened for method.