# Display value based on Check Box select or un select?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have four check box in my results page this page called `calculate.php`.

my check Box code Looks like

```
<input type="text" name="upfrontmipamt" id="upfrontmipamt" class="txt" size="7" onChange="javascript:upfrontMIPAmountChanged(true)" maxlength="7" />
</div>

<div class="col-md-1 padding-lft">
    <img id="upfront1" src="Content/Images/percent.png" onclick="changeupfront1(event,this.src)" style="cursor:pointer;margin-left:2px" />
</div>

<div class="col-md-1 padding-lft" style="right:13px;top:3px">
    <input id="chkUFtoLoan-1" name="S" type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

My question is if the user checked the Include In `Calc` button from the input page. They should all be defaulted to checked (*as we are defaulting to adding the UPFRONT MIP balance to the loan*). But if they uncheck the checkboxes, then the value gets placed in the Buyer Costs To Close Section.

MY  results page :

**About your Loan**

```
<div class="result-header">
    <p>About Your Loan</p>
</div>

<div class="row content black">
    <label id="Label20" class="pull-left">Financed Upfront MIP</label>
    <label id="ss_financedmip" class="pull-right">$
        <?php echo round($arrSecondBox["ssupfrontmipamt"],2);?>
    </label>

</div>
```

**Buyer close to section**

```
<div class="result-header">
    <p>Buyer Cost To Close</p>
</div>

<div class="row content green">
    <label id="Label152" for="purchasePrice" class="pull-left ">Upfront MIP Financed</label>
    <label id="ss_financedmip" class="pull-right">$
        <?php echo round($arrSecondBox["ssupfrontmipamt"],2);?>
    </label>
</div>
```

this code of results if user select check box values goes to  `ABOUT YOUR LOAN`  and if user check values  goes To `BUYER CLOSE TO SECTION` ..

i am trying post value one page to another is   value not passing ? please any one give some idea about it ?

Comment: You question is fairly incomprehensible; I don't think your results page is `calculate` (unless you're doing a postback). also, when you state ***"My question is.."** It should not be *business logic/contraint considerations*; that is background information, and it is quite irrelevant to your issue..

Comment: if I had to guess why the value isn't passing, I would guess that you don't have a `form` tag or that it is improper, or that you aren't specifying the `name` property/attribute on the `checkbox` inputs.

Comment: i have used post method its value not passing sir   my post method  $checkbox1 = $_POST["S"];

Comment: that is for receiving the post (form-urlencode) variable.. you need to post from the input page to the result page by putting your input elements in a form tag (presumably your on and only form tag on the page) and doing a submit, or form.submit..

Comment: ok @thank you Brett casWell

Answer (score 0):

I don't have WAMP running, so I can't validate the php aspect of this ... 'solution';

The following html code snippet is intended to highlight the basic form submit mechanics, using `GET` method;

```css
div#note {background-color:whitesmoke; font-weight:700; border:0.1em solid silver;padding:0.3em 3em;margin:1em;text-align:center;line-height:2em;}
form {display:block;text-align:center;padding:1em 3em 3em;margin:3em 4em auto;border:0.08em solid silver;}
div {display:block;}
label {display:inline-block;width:120px;text-align:right;padding:0em 1em;line-height:2em;}
input[type="submit"] {line-height:2.5em; height:2.5em; padding:0 1em;margin-top:3em;cursor:pointer;}
form > span {font-style: italic;display:block;padding:0em;width:auto;margin:0 3em 3em;text-align:right;}
code {background-color:lightgray;display:block;padding:1.5em;margin:1em;}
code em {display:block;}
```

```html
<div id="note"><span> This demo will not execute on stacksnippet, due to iframe sandbox security settings</div>
  
  
  <code>
    <em>&lt;php?</em>
    <em>$checked = $_GET['choices'];</em>
    <em>for($i=0; $i &lt; count($checked); $i++){</em>
    <em style="padding-left:3em;">echo "Selected " . $checked[$i] . "";</em>
    <em>}</em>
    <em>?&gt;</em>
  </code>

<form name="myForm" id="form1" method="get">
  <span>If you omit the action attribute, this will be a postback</span>
  <!-- action="/" is omitted -->
  <div>
    <label for="firstchoice">First Choice:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="firstchoice" name="choices[]" checked="checked" value="first" />
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <label for="firstchoice">Second Choice:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="secondchoice" name="choices[]" value="second" />
  </div>
  
    
  <div>
    <label for="firstchoice">Third Choice:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="thirdchoice" name="choices[]" value="third" />
  </div>
  
    
  <div>
    <label for="firstchoice">Fourth Choice:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="fourthchoice" name="choices[]" value="fourth" />
  </div>
  
  <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

---

#### References

- [Make array from checkbox form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516847/make-array-from-checkbox-form)
- [php form action php self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862735/php-form-action-php-self)